# Get request length to fix "Maximum request length excedded"

Tags: .net, xml, vb.net

I'm dealing with an issue on my .NET application. I'm calling a web service to interact with my DB. But I have a problem.

I'm sending XML content through a list on my web service. But as soon as I call it, it is immediatly stop due to the error. I tried to decrease list length. It worked for my 2 first lists but not the last one.

At the beginning, I had a list of 43k objects of a class. I realized it was too much for my web service.

```vb
' ListOfElements is a List(Of List(Of T))
Dim addedObject as New List(Of T)
For Each element As List(Of T) In ListOfElements
    ' ListOfElements contains 5 List(Of T)
    ' element contains 7.5k T object
    WS.InsertInDb(element, addedObject)
Next
```

So instead of it, I cut that list into sublist of 10k objects of a class. It was working but not anymore after the third call. I tried to decrease it to 7.5k, work until the forth call.

Do you know how I can get my request length to have a better understanding of what it is sent to my webservice.

Because one day, it was working, the day after, not anymore.

Comment: What's the **maximum request length** limit of the web service? Do you have control of both the .NET app and the web service?

Comment: The maximum request length is the one by default. I do have access to both but I cannot edit web.config of the web service. That's why I have to work only on the .NET app

Comment: It's not clear what is the web service? Assuming it's `WCF` then it should be 4096 kb ? It could also be limited in `IIS`. Have you tried limiting the request length to 4096 kb ?

Comment: No, I can't. I'm working with a web service host on a different server, which do not allow me to push edited web.config. I already saw that 4096 kb limit but I'm not even sure why I'm exceding that limit.

Comment: why you can't limit the .NET App request length? Where is the code of that app that sends the request?

Comment: I try to limit it, more and more. At first, I had 10k instances in my list. Working like a charm. I decreased it to 7500, still the same issue but on the 4 lists. I will precise it in my question

Comment: please edit the question and show the code and how you're checking what's your apps request length, it's impossible to guess what's happening based on these comments.

Comment: I just edited it. I cannot show to much of it as it is a client code

Comment: need to make sure each request is below 4096 kb so when inserting, either close the connection when the exception is thrown or calculate each request length - in both cases you'll need more than 1 request once reaching the 4096 kb limit.

Comment: My question was specificly know how to calculate a request lentgh ?

Comment: if this is ASMX with SOAP and using the legacy add service in VS it would be easier to catch the exception and then close the connection and reopen it, rinse & repeat until everything is sent.

Answer (score 0):

i found where the size exceeded.

On the second object sent to the WS (addedObject), I was creating a list of T inserted for my mail report. As much as this list was growing, I was increasing the request despite me.

Thanks for the clue